# Scoped resources - missing required keys: [:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I'm getting problem "No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"picks", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]"

I'd like to have example.com/staff/picks so I made scope in routes. It was ok until I create form for posting new post. It can't show post now because of missing id.

**routes.db**

```
  resources :places
  resources :events
  root "search#index"
  post 'find' => 'search#find', as: :find


  get '/staff', to: redirect('staff/picks')

  scope 'staff' do
    resources :picks
    resources :discover
  end
```

**picks_controller.rb**

```
class PicksController < ApplicationController
before_action :staff_validate
  def index
    @pickplaces = PickPlaces.all.order('created_at DESC')
  end

  def new
    @pickplaces = PickPlaces.new
  end

  def create
    @pickplaces = PickPlaces.new(pickplaces_params)
    if @pickplaces.save
      redirect_to pick_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
    @pickplaces = PickPlaces.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @pickplaces = PickPlaces.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @pickplaces = PickPlaces.find(params[:id])
    if @pickplaces.update(params[:pickplaces].permit(:title, :about, :location, :kind))
      redirect_to @pickplaces
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private

  def pickplaces_params
    params.require(:pickplaces).permit(:title, :about, :location, :kind)
  end
end
```

**staff_controller.rb**

```
class StaffController < ApplicationController
before_action :staff_validate
  def index

  end
end
```

**new.html.slim - Views/Picks**

```
h1 Add some place that people will love
= form_for :pickplaces, url: picks_path do |f|

  p
    = f.label "Title"
    = f.text_field :title, placeholder: 'Golden Gate'

  p
    = f.label "Location"
    = f.text_field :location, placeholder: 'California, US'

  p
    | Select place type
    = f.radio_button(:kind, "city", :checked => true)
    = f.label(:placetype_city, "City")
    = f.radio_button(:kind, "bridge")
    = f.label(:placetype_bridge, "Bridge")
    = f.radio_button(:kind, "other")
    = f.label(:placetype_other, "Other")

  p
    = f.label "About"
    = f.text_area :about, placeholder: "World's most amazing place"

  = f.submit "Go Public!"
```

**index.html.slim - Views/Picks**

```
h1 Staff Picks

- @pickplaces.each do |pickplaces|

  h2
    = link_to pickplaces.title, pick_path(@picks)
```

It's bit dirty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your index view you're using the instance variable `@picks` which hasn;t been set anywhere, leading to the routing error.

Instead you should use the `pickplaces` variable from the collection:

```
- @pickplaces.each do |pickplaces|
  h2
    = link_to pickplaces.title, pick_path(pickplaces)
```

Comment: Thanks! That's it! And how about redirect in controller? When I post new post it should redirect user to post just created
//Edit: Solved! redirect_to pick_path(@pickplaces) I forgot @. Thank you once more!